# Reporting app crashes: PLCrashReporter vs uncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: ios, web-services, crash-reports, uncaught-exception, plcrashreporter

I need to send app crashes stacktraces to a certain web service (I was given such requirement). It looks like there is a third-party framework, `PLCrashReporter`, that allows to send such info to the web service you want, is that right?

On the other hand, I've read that it is also possible to get the app crash info in an `uncaughtExceptionHandler` method, to write it to a file, and send it when app launches again, is that also right?

After reading a little about both options, I have some questions. I just want to send crashes info to my particular web service, so:

1. Is integrating `PLCrashReporter` worth to do only what I need?
2. Is such functionality of `PLCrashReporter` under the `MIT` license? And will Apple approve it for release in `App Store`? My app will be a commercial one.
3. Is there any other crash reporting framework I could use to call my own web service?
4. Regarding `uncaughtExceptionHandler`, I read somewhere that it is not reliable to report app crashes this way, is that correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. It's fine. I've been using it for years in my commercial iOS apps.
3. Such questions are off-topic.
4. Use PLCrashReporter - it does all the hard stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding 2, will then showing the license text in attributions in the app be enough?

Comment: I have a "license" section off of the "About" page in my app where I show the PLCrashReporter license.